# How does a network port work?(operating system)

Tags: networking, operating-system, port

I understand that there is a limit of ports available (2^16) but I don't understand how an operating system is managing the ports. Is there like a microcontroller inside that is multiplexing all the opened ports? How is a port actually making a connection with the operating system? Is a port connecting to a specific process in the OS? I know that my questions are vague and ițm very sorry about that. Maybe ișm thinking the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port is an application(or process) specific construct representing an endpoint on a host. A remote party can identify an application(or process) on the host with the unique port it is bound to.

Unix like operating systems provide `bind(2)` system call to bind your process to a specific port so that the operating system can forward all the messages destined to a port to the right process.

Port is represented by a 16-bit number ranging from 1 to 65535. However, the port numbers below 1024 are reserved for core network services.

Answer (score 3):

A port is just a number in the operating system, or more accurately in the TCP/IP protocol stack. It isn't a piece of physical hardware. No microcontroller, no magic. Just software.